# $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x}f(x-t)dt$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x}f(x-t)dt=f(x-a)$ I reached this after doing a variable substitution, and applying the fundamental theorem of calculus.

However, what would $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt$ equal to? I can't use the same reasoning, since I would just push the x to the function $g$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of the Leibniz rule for derivative under integral sign?

Comment: @OriaGruber Many thanks! I didn't know that there was a more general version in which the bounds were also allowed to depend on x. ;)

Comment: @OriaGruber Would the Leibniz rule also work in the case $\int^{\infty}_x $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Leibnizt rule

The first one is $$    \frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x}f(x-t)dt=
f(0)+ \int_a^{x}f'(x-t)dt= f(0)-f(0)+f(x-a)$$
and the second is

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt = f(0)g(x)+ \int_a^{x} f'(x-t)g(t)dt
$$

Comment: Guy, would the Leibniz rule also be valid for $\int^{\infty}_x$?

Comment: yes if the integral converges as well

Comment: Guy, I was trying to apply the Leibniz rule to this equation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505510/solutions-to-ut-a-uta-int-0tut-sgus-ads-int-infty-t-vt-sgus

Comment: I gave and insight there.  it is similar problem