# Solutions to $u(t,a)=U(t)a+\int_0^tU(t-s)G(u(s,a))ds-\int^{\infty}_t V(t-s)G(u(s,a))ds$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Let $B=\begin{bmatrix}
    P & 0 \\
    0 & Q
\end{bmatrix}$, where $P$ is $k\times k$ matrix whose eigenvalues have negative real part, and $Q$ is $(n-k)\times (n-k)$ matrix whose eigenvalues have positive real part.

Let $\dot y=By+G(y)$,

Why are the solutions $y$ to this equation, are also solutions to the following integral equation:

$$u(t,a)=U(t)a+\int_0^tU(t-s)G(u(s,a))ds-\int^{\infty}_t V(t-s)G(u(s,a))ds$$?

Where 
$U(t)=\begin{bmatrix}e^{Pt} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and $V(t)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{Qt} \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Two options are offered  to you in other to apply Leibniz rule. First if the integral exists at t=0 then then just apply the Chasles relation . or second the integrand exists and makes sense at infty. therefore you can apply the change of variables  turning your second integral from t=0 to t=1/x then apply Leibniz rule as well. sorry I cannot give you the answer I am using my phone at the moment.